# Observe changes to nested list in Room entities

Tags: android, observable, rx-java, android-room

**Preface**

Hey I have a Room entity with a list

```
@Entity(tableName="playlists")
Playlist(
val playlistId: String, 
@Ignore val songs:List<Song>)
```

I can retrieve all playlists using junctions and relation

```
PlaylistWithSongs(
@Embedded val playlist:Playlist,
@Relation(
    parentColumn = "playlistId",
    entityColumn = "songId",
    associateBy = Junction(PlaylistSongCrossRef::class)
)
val songs:List<Song>)
```

and my current query

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM playlists")
fun getPlaylists():Observable<List<PlaylistWithSongs>>
```

**PROBLEM**

However I want to be able to observe to changes in songs, so my playlist screen will show the current number of songs after you add a song. My current query doesn't do that. It only emit on first subscribe and then changes to playlist.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest hack is to make an observable select query that returns list of songs from db. And on the next step you should use `switchMap` operator to switch every songs emit to playlist emit.

Your code will be something like that:

```
songsRepository.getSongs()
    .switchMap { playlistsRepository.getPlaylists() }
    // Do what you need
```